# ajax bugs in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, jquery

i have a controller having following script

```
class get extends CI_Controller
{
    function get_password()
    {
        $this->load->model('fetch_model');
        $user_pass=$this->fetch_model->get_password(); 
        $data['user_pass'] = json_encode($user_pass);
        echo $data['user_pass'];
    }
}
```

and a script on view page as this

```
function get_password(){
    $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>admin.php/get/get_password",function(data)
    {      
        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
        {
            $('#password').val(data[i].password);
            $('#username').val(data[i].username);
        }
    },"json");
}
```

now if i use the following script in model then the ajax post is working perfectly..

```
class fetch_model extends CI_Model
{
    function get_password()
    {
        return  $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM td_admin_user")->result_array();
    }
}
```

but when i change the model script into this, then the ajax script isnt working

```
class fetch_model extends CI_Model
{
    function get_password()
    {
        foreach($this->db->query("SELECT * FROM td_admin_user")->result() as $r_pass)
        {
            $pass=$r_pass->password;
            $user=$r_pass->username;
        }
        $user_pass=array('username'=>$user,
                         'password'=>$pass);
        return $user_pass;
    }
}
```

but to be very frankly, i need to send data in the following way

```
$user_pass  =   array('username'=>$user, 'password'=>$pass);
```

and not as result_array()

so please help me in this context, thanks in advance

Comment: why are you using foreach in the model? are you trying to get multiple passwords and usernames?

Comment: if you are trying to get multiple passwords and usernames and return it to your controller, you are overwriting `$pass` and `$user` in each iteration of your `foreach` loop. Thereby only returning one username and password

Comment: i have only one row, i know its useless to use foreach loop, but thats not the matter of concern...

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug! Did you even look at what type of data is returned in each call?

In your JS, you are using:

```
$('#password').val(data[i].password);
```

Where `data` is an indexed array - exactly what is returned by `->result_array()`

But you want it to be a key based array:

```
$user_pass=array('username'=>$user, 'password'=>$pass);
```

If that's the case, you should forget using the for loop on JS (specially if your query only results in one row) and use

```
 $('#password').val(data.password);
```

Instead.

Also look at `console.log` (if you are using firebug/developer tools) and try `print_r` or `var_dump` on the PHP side to understand the data formats you are returning.

Comment: i used this script  <script type="text/javascript">
       function get_password(){
       $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>admin.php/get/get_password",function(data)
        {         alert(data.password);
                  $('#password').val(data.password);
               
        });
    }
</script>    but still it alerts undefined, however if i call the controller, it shows the accyrate result